# Only want to print specific pages using livecycle designer ES3

Tags: java, livecycle

I am creating a letter with a front end interface for users to complete. When clicking the print button I do not want the front end page to print, only from the second page onwards. Is there any script which will do this or is there another way of making this work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to click event of the button. The second argument says from which page start printing (it is zero based), the third one says what is the last page.

```
xfa.host.print(1, "1", (xfa.host.numPages -1).toString(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```